# How to test Jenkinsfile separately from source code?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

With the pipeline-as-code introduced with jenkins 2.x, we can review/edit the pipeline definition with the application code source in an SCM, as a jenkinsfile.
But when we edit the jenkinsfile and we want to test it, this could have impacts on the rest of the application code source.

How can we test separately the jenkinsfile from the code source?
Any Jenkins Plugin ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Jenkins Pipeline Unit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit), it allows you to write unit tests for your Jenkinsfile.